# Vnc Ubuntu 14.04 destop don't show menus icon

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, icons, vnc

[image]

Just like the picture shows above, no application icon showed in the taskbar, my `/home/sdfsd/.vnc/xstartup` file are like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1  
unset SESSION_MANAGER  
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS 

gnome-session &
gnome-panel &  
gnome-settings-daemon &  
metacity &  
nautilus &  
gnome-terminal &
```

I don't know what's wrong with it after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1):

This could work for you :

open a terminal and go root by running

`sudo -i`

run following commands to Update:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

Install Ubuntu Desktop & Gnome-fallback by running following command one at a time:

```
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install gnome-session-fallback
```

Once installed ubuntu desktop and gnome-fallback Install and start GDM

```
apt-get install gdm
```

if you already installed GDM ,gnome before use

```
dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

and choose GDM

```
service gdm start
```

once choosen gdm, Install TightVNCServer and set password

```
apt-get install tightvncserver
vncserver -geometry 1024x768 :1 //It will ask for a password
vncserver -kill :1
```

Once all this succeed edit xstartup file, i.e, ~/.vnc/xstartup:

```
nano ~/.vnc/xstartup
```

Paste this in:

```
#!/bin/sh

unset SESSION_MANAGER
/etc/X11/xinint/

xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
#x-terminal-emulator -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
x-window-manager &
# Fix to make GNOME work
export XKL_XMODMAP_DISABLE=1
#/etc/X11/Xsession

gnome-session --session=gnome-fallback &
```

Then start a new vnc connection:

```
vncserver -geometry 1024x768 :1
```

And login, you should see a screen with a menu bar at the top that looks a bit like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z2GJ.jpg

**or simple solution use xfce4 instead of gnome**

```
# apt-get install gnome-core xfce4 firefox nano -y --force-yes
```

and use this xstartup file

```
#!/bin/sh
unset SESSION_MANAGER
unset DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
startxfce4 &

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
```

xfce4 is way better and faster than gnome for vnc on ubuntu.

Comment: Hi,I just follow your instructions to install tightvncserver, but when I run vncserver, it display this error:Undefined subroutine &main::INADDR_ANY called at /usr/bin/vncserver line 459.